# number of times the combinations of strings ( length>3) occurred in the given ArrayList

Tags: java, string, arraylist, hashmap

I want to find the number of times the combinations of strings (whose length is more than 3) occurred in the given input.

```
input:
scientists found way to reduce global warming
scientists, found way to minimize water pollution
scientists said that they are successful
Rony said that they are successful
johnny said that he failed

desired output:
scientists found-2
said that-3
```

"scientists found" is in 1st and 2nd statement,

"said that" is in 3rd ,4th and 5th statement,

"they are successful" is not included as length of "are" is not more than 3.

i have divided my program in blocks and added comment of what these blocks are doing, how to get the desired output?? is there a more efficient solution for this ??

```
package project1;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

public class combo{
//----------Block 1 starts---------------------------------------
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    ArrayList<String> exampleList = new ArrayList<>();
    exampleList.add("scientists found way to reduce global warming".toLowerCase());
    exampleList.add("scientists, found way to minimize water pollution".toLowerCase());
    exampleList.add("scientists, said that they are successful".toLowerCase());
   exampleList.add("Rony, said that they are successful".toLowerCase());
   exampleList.add("johnny, said that he failed".toLowerCase());

Map<String, Integer> keywordList = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
ArrayList<String> strmatch=new ArrayList<>();
for(int i=0;i<exampleList.size();i++){
    String[] tokens = exampleList.get(i).split("[ ,-;()//:']");
    for (String token : tokens)
    {
        if(token.length()>3){
        if(!keywordList.containsKey(token))
            keywordList.put(token,1);
        else{
            keywordList.put(token,keywordList.get(token)+1);
        }
        }
    }
      for (int j=0;j<tokens.length;j++)//content of tokens array 
        {
        System.out.println(tokens[j]);  //to check content of tokens.
        }
}
//------------Block 1 ends---------------------------------------

//content of keywordList
/*for (String name: keywordList.keySet()){

            String key =name.toString();
            String value = keywordList.get(name).toString();  
            System.out.println(key + " " + value); //to check keywordList content. 
} */
//------------Block 2 starts-------------------------------------
System.out.println(keywordList.size());
Iterator it = keywordList.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    if((int)pair.getValue()<2)
        it.remove();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue()); /*to get 
                  content of keywordList which are repeated more than once.*/  
}
//-----------Block 2 ends--------------------------------------
//-----------Block 3 starts------------------------------------
 it = keywordList.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " ::" + pair.getValue());
    strmatch.add((String)pair.getKey());
}
//-----------Block 3 ends----------------------------------------

//-----------Block 4 starts--------------------------------------

System.out.println(strmatch);//content of strmatch
String[] str= new String[strmatch.size()];
//int[][] variable2=new int[keywordList.size()][keywordList.size()];
for(int i=0;i<exampleList.size();i++){
    for(int j=0;j<strmatch.size();j++)
        for (int k=0;k<strmatch.size();k++){
            if(j==k)
                continue;
            if(exampleList.get(i).contains(strmatch.get(j))&&exampleList.get(i).contains(strmatch.get(k)))
                str[i]=strmatch.get(j)+" "+strmatch.get(k);
        }
}
//-----------Block 4 ends----------------------------------------

for(int p=0;p<strmatch.size();p++)//contents of str array
    {
     System.out.println(str[p]);   //to get desired output
    }
}
```

Comment: The reason you don't have an answer here yet may be that you've made it a lot of work to figure out what it is you're actually looking for. Basically, you've said "here is what I want to do", and then "how do I make this code I've written work?" Now, I can suggest a few modifications. 1: In what way does your code currently not work? List your test input, expected output, and real output, and maybe we can help find the problem.

Comment: 2: Try to isolate your problem before posting. Here, you have one very large method encompassing everything. Break it up into maybe 4-5 different methods, test the output of each individual method, and thus identify where exactly the problem is happening, and if you can't figure out why, then ask us a more specific question about how to fix a much smaller portion of code.

Comment: Personally, I haven't read your code, because I just don't have time right now to read and fully comprehend all of it. If you follow my first suggestion, it will help pinpoint the problem, and we will know where within the code we might want to look, and be more inclined to help. If you follow the second suggestion, there will simply be much less code to look over, and it will be much clearer what, in fact, we should be looking to fix, allowing for us to give you a much quicker answer.

Comment: will take care from next time , I am a beginner to this platform so.... anywys thanks...